# mongoDb conditional projection query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some data as below:

```
{MS: 'MS1', fileName: 'file1', RSCP: 75, EcNo: 10, ...}
{MS: 'MS2', fileName: 'file1', RSCP: 76, EcNo: 11, ...}
{MS: 'MS3', fileName: 'file1', RSCP: 77, EcNo: 12, ...}
{MS: 'MS4', fileName: 'file1', RSCP: 78, EcNo: 13, ...}
```

I need to query data like that:

```
find all documents that fileName = file1
if MS = MS1 return RSCP
if MS = MS2 return EcNo
```

how can I query mongo like this in one query?

Comment: How about `MS3` & `MS4` ? From above sample docs can you give us required o/p !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** filter docs with condition */
  {
    $match: {
      fileName: "file1"
    }
  },
  /** Re-create `EcNo` & `RSCP` fields based on conditions 
   * `$$REMOVE` completely removes the field
   */
  {
    $addFields: {
      EcNo: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$MS", "MS1" ] }, "$$REMOVE", "$EcNo" ] },
      RSCP: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$MS", "MS2" ] }, "$$REMOVE", "$RSCP" ] }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8zfuUWgSBTi)